# Dotnet Core 3.1 Background Service is not working correctly on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, backgroundworker, background-service

I've Web API which working on Linux server. Project has background service. When I launch with "dotnet app.dll" command there is no problem, but the project working on Apache Server background service is not working. Here is my code down below.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await checkTerminalWorks();
                await Task.Delay(300000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        
        private async Task checkTerminalWorks()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Device Connection Start {DateTime.Now}");
            var terminals = await dbContext.Terminaller.ToListAsync();
            var terminalWorks = await dbContext.TerminalIslemleri.OrderBy(o => o.Zaman).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var item in terminalWorks)
            {

                //business logic

            }
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Hosted services work just fine on any platform. They have nothing to do with the OS itself, they are essentially singleton classes with a single long-running method. As for your specific problem, what is it? What does `the project working on Apache Server background service is not working` mean? Do you get an error? Is the database running? Are you logging any exceptions? Where did the `dbContext` come from? If it's injected, it's almost certainly disposed by the time `checkTerminalWorks` is called. `AddDbContext` registers DbContexts as scoped services

Comment: [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) explains how to use scoped services like a DbContext in singleton services like a BackgroundService

Comment: Actually when i checked my logs, it said error on my business logic.

Comment: It said "Access to the path '/var/netcore/netcoreapp3.1/Bilgi005.txt' is denied."

Comment: "Access to the path <filename> is denied" points to a file permissions problem. Try `ls -l /var/netcore/netcoreapp3.1/` and see if the file permissions are what you expect. This moves the problem off-topic so I suggest you ask another question if you have problems with file permissions.

Comment: Can you say any solution ? It is work with dotnet app.dll command,  but with Apache Server not working. Is it related with service file ?

Comment: It's probably due to a bug in the application itself - why is the application trying to write in the *runtime's* folder? Which code is trying to do that? It's not the code you posted.  If you post the full exception text you'll see which method tried to write to that folder in the stack trace.

Comment: Log and post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. The error is caused by code you didn't post. Whatever is trying to write the file `Bilgi005.txt`  in `/var/netcore/netcoreapp3.1/` instead of an application-specific path

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, a file permission problem is not connected with question posted and Bilgi05.txt does not appear to have any conneciton with the code snippet presented. Therefore, as I suggested, speculation and further help is off-topic so the poster should ask another question.

Comment: @DanielDearlove that's not how SO works. The poster should add the rest of the code and the full exception details. That's not speculation, that's standard procedure for debugging questions. It's so standard, there's a pre-defined `Close` reason for this, `Needs Debugging Details: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.`

Comment: @DanielDearlove questions should be deleted and reposted only if there's no way to fix them. That's not the case here. The question *can* be improved by posting the standard debugging info - full exception text and the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @DanielDearlove and finally, this isn't about permissions at all. Trying to write to `/var/netcore/netcoreapp3.1/` on Linux is similar to trying to write to `C:\Windows` on Windows. There's no valid reason for an application to do this. The problem is writing to the wrong folder, not file permissions